# how to use sum and max in one query

Tags: sql-server

I have a table

```
tblPay
(
    CID bigint,
    PartyIdID bigint,
    PartyName varchar(50),
    AgentName varchar(50), 
    Agent bigint,
    Amount decimal(18,2),
    RecAmount decimal(18,2),
    OutStanding decimal(18,2)
)
```

I want to select sum of Amount,RecAmount group by PartyId and I also want to select Last Outstanding entry of each PartyID. For this i use following query.

```
SELECT  DISTINCT CID, 
        Party.AccLedger_ID PartyID, 
        Party.AccLedger_Name PartyName,
        Agent.AccLedger_Name AgentName,
        Agent.AccLedger_ID AgentID,
        sum(S.Amount) Amount,
        Sum(S.RecAmount) RecAmount,
        S.OutStanding 
Group by PartyID,
         Cid,
         Party.AccLedger_ID,
         Party.AccLedger_Name,
         Agent.AccLedger_Name,
         Agent.AccLedger_ID,
         S.OutStanding
```

But i am unable to achieve the sum of Amount,RecAmount and Last Outstanding Record of each Party. Can someone help me here.

[image]

This is the Answer i got.

Comment: Please add some detail describing what's going wrong. "Unable to achieve" is vague. Are you getting an error instead of results? If so, include the error message in your question. Are the results not what you expect? If so, include an example or description of the results vs. what you're expecting. In lieu of that, I'd consider removing `DISTINCT` as a starting point. Many, including myself, [consider `DISTINCT` a code smell](http://arnosoftwaredev.blogspot.com/2011/01/is-select-distinct-code-smell.html)

Comment: Post what you've got? and what you are expecting?

Comment: You said you want to group by PartyId and then in your query you got a gazillion of other variable there.

Comment: I Edited my question.  I want Sum of AMount and RecAmount. Also i want last entry of Ourstanding.

Comment: Your query is missing the from clause

Comment: How do you determine which record in `tblPay` is the **last** so that you can include the "last outstanding" value? I don't see any date fields or an `ORDER BY` in your example query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your records are inserted in `tblPay.CID` order, use a subquery

```
SELECT  p.PartyID,
        p.PartyName,
        SUM(p.Amount) AS PartyAmount,
        SUM(p.RecAmount) AS PartyRecAmount,
        (SELECT TOP 1 OutStanding FROM tblPay p2 WHERE p.PartyID = p2.PartyId ORDER BY CID DESC) AS LastOutStanding
FROM tblPay p
GROUP BY p.PartyID, p.PartyName
```

or an `OUTER APPLY`:

```
SELECT  p.PartyID,
        p.PartyName,
        SUM(p.Amount) AS PartyAmount,
        SUM(p.RecAmount) AS PartyRecAmount,
        lastRecord.OutStanding AS LastOutStanding
FROM tblPay p
OUTER APPLY
(
    SELECT TOP 1 OutStanding
    FROM tblPay p2
    WHERE p.PartyID = p2.PartyId
    ORDER BY CID DESC
) lastRecord
GROUP BY p.PartyID, p.PartyName
```

or, as [JamieD77](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1221684/jamied77) suggests in his answer, use a CTE.

Answer (score 2):

use a cte to get your tblPay information and join that to your other tables on the last record

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT 
        CID,
        PartyName,
        SUM(Amount) OVER (PARTION BY PartyIdID) Amount,
        SUM(RecAmount) OVER (PARTITION BY PartyIdID) RecAmount,
        OutStanding,
        -- only assuming your CID determines order since you have no date?
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PartyIdID ORDER BY CID DESC) Rn 
    FROM tblPay
) 
SELECT  Party.*,
        Agent.*,
        p.CID,
        p.PartyName,
        p.Amount,
        p.RecAmount,
        p.Oustanding
FROM    Party JOIN Agent
        JOIN cte p ON p.PartyIdID = Party.AccLedger_ID AND p.Rn = 1
```